# Xcode - sort files by name, put folders (groups) first

Tags: xcode

When clicking on **Sort by Name**, Xcode sorts my files and folders mixed. This results in dragging the folders back manually to the front each and every time, and that's pretty tedious.

With **Sort by Type**, folders go to the bottom which is even worse.

Is there a way to sort the folders and then the files alphabetically?

Comment: Just FYI: I got used to folders being at the bottom and I'm now using Sort by Type. It's not ideal, since it does not keep the alphabetical order if there are multiple types of files in a group, but it's still much better than manual reordering for every group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working on a Swift Package, the file structure is automatically ordered so that folders come first. Here's how to take advantage of this with a normal Xcode project ([here's the source of this info](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-package-manager-example-apps-can-you-do-it/29681/4)):

- Make a new Swift package
- Create a new Xcode project using the package's project folder as the folder
- Open the new project you just created
- Work within this project, but create the files inside the Swift package

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with UI, but you can try to write a custom script that does that. There are libraries that are able to work with the Xcode project format, for example [CocoaPods Xcodeproj](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj). This should be a good starting point.